# React full calendar dragging save to state

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, drag

Hello i use dragging in full calendar and i save events in a state but it duplicates the event in frontend, see example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-dragging-6js74

how can i store the event in the state without duplicating,

i think it shows one from the state and one from the calendar it self but i need to show only state one because i also store events added on click and on select in the same state.

any solutions please?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). An external demo is nice, but you must also add relevant code **here** or else people can vote to close your question as off-topic. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway I'm pretty sure you're right about it adding one event from the state and one from the drop operation. My suggestion would be to handle [eventReceive](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive) instead of "drop", which then gives you access to the event object added to the calendar - that way you can then delete that event, once you've also added it to the state. I think that would probably solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much.. it works fine now with eventReceive, please write that in an answer so i can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about it adding one event from the state and one from the drop operation.

My suggestion would be to handle the [eventReceive](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive) callback instead of the "drop" callback. In eventReceive you get you direct access to the event object added to the calendar - that way you can then delete that event (using the event's [remove method](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-remove), once you've also added it to the state.